# Random numbers To a letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to attach a random number to a letter, I mean, any letter will be assigned with a random number. The problem, Is that a number, can't be the same number for 2 letters. Another problem, is this:

Currently I have:

```
Input: A
Output: 36

Input: AA
Output: 3614
```

What I want is:

```
Input: AA
Output: 3636
```

Here is my code:

```
from random import randint

cifrar = input("Escriba el texto: ")
diction = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for diction in cifrar:
    a = randint(0, 36)
    print(a)
```

[Here is an image of my current input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9j2S.png)

In this Image example, what I want is the same numbers, because all is A

Comment: How do you mean "attach"? Are you trying to create a cipher of sorts?

Comment: What is your question? What do you want your code to output?

Comment: The `input` is not part of I need, only I need a random number for a letter

Comment: Can numbers be used twice? What range can the numbers be in?

Comment: I mean, a random election for any letter: A=36, B=12, C=13... But when I repeat the letters, The random number changes. An example:
Input = A
Output = 36

but

Input=AA
Output=36 12

Comment: @Nathan No, Only 1 number per letter

Comment: I think you need to expand out what you need this to do a bit more. The question as posed does not encompass the full scope of what you need

Comment: what is wrong with your code? because according to what you describe in the comments it seems to do what you want...

Comment: thanks @C.Nivs , now I will edit it

Comment: @Tomerikoo It doesn't do what I want. Refresh the page, please

Comment: You'll want a `dictionary` for this

Comment: @C.Nivs Alredy did a dictionary :)

Comment: If you are referring to the code in the post, that is not a dictionary - it's a list

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh. So, How it does a dctionary in python? I was thinking that was a dictionary

Comment: Now I posted an Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to think is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), is actually just a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists). Furthermore, you don't actually use that list, because the loop assigns a new value for the variable `diction` on each iteration. Then, for each letter of the input prints a random number.

What you want is to really use a dictionary to create a **static** mapping between each letter to a random number:

```py
import string
import random

diction = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, random.sample(range(36), 26)))

cifrar = input("Escriba el texto: ")
for letter in cifrar:
    print(diction.get(letter.lower(), letter))
```

Example run:

```
Escriba el texto: AA!BB$CC
14
14
!
3
3
$
24
24
```

Comment: Wow, it works, but doesn't accept spaces and special caracters, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: @ArionSintesSintes I have edited so that it is possible with spaces and characters too

Comment: Thanks, It works correctly. Now I have to know HOW it works, but I will search it or try it for myself. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ArionSintesSintes the way I built the dictionary is really not the most basic one, but [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) you can find more details of how to create dictionaries using the `dict` constructor. It is really handy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
from random import shuffle
numbers = [i for i in range(26)]
letters = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in numbers]
```

Create lists of letters and numbers

```
numbers = shuffle(numbers)
```

Shuffle the order and combine

```
print(zip(letters, numbers))
```

Comment: I don't understand how it's works, and it don't do it. I'm trying to convert a letter to a number, but this enter is part from an imput. I can post an image of my output